# How do I solve this complex polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, factoring

I'm a bit stuck on this question, it asks to solve $P(z)=0$ over $\Bbb{C}$  and factorise $P(z)$ fully over $\Bbb{R}$.
$$P(z)=5z^4-11z^3+16z^2-11z+5$$
 Am I supposed to solve this by using the substitution method (i.e. $z=y-\frac{b} a$)? If so, where do I go from there?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: note the symmetry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equations of this type where the coefficients located at equal distances from the middle one are equal can be solved in a standard way. First, notice that $z=0$ is not a root, so you can divide by $z^2$ and then you can group as follows:
$$5z^2-11z+16-\frac{11}{z}+\frac{5}{z^2}=0$$
$$5\left(z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}\right)-11\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)+16=0$$
Then, let $y=z+\frac{1}{z}$ and notice $z^2+\frac{1}{z^2}=y^2-2$. This transforms your equation into a quadratic one.

Comment: That makes it a lot clearer to me now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: it factors as the product of two quadratics with integer coefficients, both of which have the same symmetry.